# How to improve executive time using webdriver with python

Tags: python, loops, selenium-webdriver

In the code below I am trying to import the odds of several soccer games in different url. I used webdriver.firefox to navigate to each of these webpage. My problem is the time of execution which is to long.

In my case There are 25 url links but in a first time I make a test with only 4 url links. The execution time is 2,37 min so that for 25 url links It will take about 20 minutes. It is too much time.
So I would like to know if It is possible to improve and optimaze this time

Here is my code :

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf­-8 ­-*-

from selenium import webdriver
import statistics as stat
import numpy as np

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
url = 'https://www.coteur.com/cotes-foot.php'
driver.get(url)

#Store url associated with the soccer games
url_links = []
for i in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[contains(@href, "match/cotes-")]'):
    url_links.append(i.get_attribute('href'))

driver.close()
print(len(url_links))

for l in range(0, 4):
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get(url_links[l])

    #Store odds into table
    odds = []
    header = []
    for i in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//button[contains(@class, "btn btn-default btn-xs btncote")]'):
        odds.append(i.text)

    for i in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//th[contains(@width, "20%")]'):
        header.append(i.text)

    rows = int(len(odds)/3) 
    columns = 3
    odds = [float(i) for i in odds]
    odds = np.array(odds)
    header = np.array(header)
    odds = odds.reshape(rows, columns)

    print(odds, '\n')
    driver.close()
```

Here is the output :

```
hao@hao-ThinkPad-T420:~$ time ./parallel.py 
25
[[1.28 5.2  7.25]
 [1.33 4.7  6.55]
 [1.33 4.6  6.5 ]
 [1.37 4.4  6.  ]
 [1.37 4.4  6.  ]
 [1.3  4.6  7.  ]
 [1.31 4.5  6.7 ]
 [1.31 4.7  6.3 ]
 [1.27 4.8  7.  ]
 [1.26 4.8  6.75]
 [1.25 4.9  6.75]
 [1.24 4.7  6.75]] 

[[1.8  3.58 3.77]
 [1.8  3.35 3.9 ]
 [1.8  3.4  3.7 ]
 [1.8  3.36 3.62]
 [1.8  3.35 3.55]
 [1.8  3.35 3.5 ]
 [1.73 3.45 3.55]
 [1.73 3.4  3.6 ]
 [1.73 3.4  3.6 ]
 [1.76 3.3  3.45]
 [1.72 3.35 3.55]] 

[[3.5  3.7  1.8 ]
 [2.98 3.51 1.96]
 [2.95 3.5  1.95]
 [2.91 3.5  1.96]
 [3.35 3.7  1.75]
 [3.22 3.6  1.81]
 [3.25 3.6  1.78]
 [3.3  3.75 1.73]
 [3.3  3.65 1.73]
 [3.3  3.6  1.72]
 [2.5  3.1  2.2 ]] 

[[3.3  3.5  2.32]
 [3.4  3.55 2.25]
 [3.4  3.55 2.25]
 [3.4  3.55 2.25]
 [3.4  3.55 2.25]
 [3.35 3.35 2.3 ]
 [3.25 3.45 2.22]
 [3.25 3.4  2.22]
 [3.3  3.45 2.15]
 [3.3  3.25 2.2 ]
 [3.15 3.3  2.17]] 


real    2m37,742s
user    1m1,416s
sys 0m11,797s
```

Comment: I don't speak French but my guess is that what you are attempting to do is against their TOS. You should read it carefully and make sure it's not. Having said that, you don't need to close and reopen the driver during each loop. Just keep the single driver instance and use it until you are done with all iterations and then close it. That should save you a little time.

Comment: The much bigger time savings would be to run this in parallel. You could run the first part of the script and write the URLs to file. Then create a data driven test that takes the URLs as input and kicks off a browser for each URL. Depending on the machine you run it on, you should have 1 core per browser per URL and it should go much, much faster.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I removed the line driver.close() in the loop and effectively It is a little more fast. Unfortunately I have 25 pages to open when I do not close them It crashed my PC So that I am trying a second method that is to say with parallel